# Deglaze in iron pan

Tags: cast-iron, seasoning-pans

I know the pan will not suffer for just a glass of wine, but wine is acid, and I know I shouldn't  use any acid into it. Also, water is not advisable in a frying iron pan. Can this remove the seasoning? I'm thinking into buying a stainless steel pan for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An occasional deglazing in a well seasoned cast iron pan is not a problem.
I wouldn't do it in a brand new one, however.
The pan continues to "season itself" each time you cook something in it.
Cast iron pans are wastly superior to steel ones, for almost all applications.

Comment: Thanks BEA, after how many times can I consider a pan well seasoned? I used to work with them, but the advise of the chef was "Never water, never tomatoes, never wine, never lemon, never vinegar" :) I like carbon steel because is a bit lighter and is more responsive to heat, expecially the 2mm thick. It should not worp if properly warmed up with a low flame

Comment: Vargan, I would consider a pan to be seasoned after about 3 weeks of daily use and well seasoned after about 3 months of frequent use. My oldest pan is now over 20 years old and is now non-stick!